# Regexp in R to match everything in between first and last occurene of some specified character

Tags: regex, r

I'd like to match everything between the first and last underscore. I use `R`.
What I have until now is this:

```
p.subject <- c('bla_bla', 'bla', 'bla_bla_bla', 'bla_bla_bla_bla')
sub('[^_]*_(.*)_[^_]*', x = p.subject, replacement = '\\1', perl = T)
```

Where 'bla' is any character except an underscore...

The result I'd like would be something like this:

```
c(NA, NA, bla, bla_bla)
```

I can't figure it out! Why does the first pattern match? It shouldn't because the pattern must have 2 underscores! Or do I have to use some kind of lookahead expression?

Your help is very welcome!

Comment: Match everything between the first and last underscore
https://regex101.com/r/qG5uI8/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub`:

```
vec <- gsub("(^[^_]+)_?|_?([^_]+$)", "", p.subject)
vec <- ifelse(nchar(vec) == 0 , NA, vec)
vec
[1] NA        NA        "bla"     "bla_bla"
```

**Data**:

```
dput(p.subject)
c("bla_bla", "bla", "bla_bla_bla", "bla_bla_bla_bla")
```

Comment: Not sure. I tested on both `3.2.3` and `3.3.0` which are working properly.

Comment: Ah, I see... the original question has all the vector elements as 1 string: `p.subject <- c('bla_bla, bla, bla_bla_bla, bla_bla_bla_bla')`

Comment: Yep, that's why I `dput` the data there, I am assuming OP has a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `str_extract`.  We use regex lookarounds to extract the pattern between the first and the last occurrence of a specified character i.e. `_`.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(p.subject, "(?<=[^_]{1,30}_).*(?=_[^_]+)")
#[1] NA        NA        "bla"     "bla_bla"
```

NOTE: We didn't use any `ifelse`.

#### data

```
p.subject <- c('bla_bla', 'bla', 'bla_bla_bla', 'bla_bla_bla_bla')
```